# From where to download compiled and ready to use MonoDev for Mono 2 under Windows?

Tags: mono

I have heard a lot about Mono and its usability compared to .NET and its cross platform support.

I tried to find a working version of MonoDev which will give me a visual way (like MS visual Studio) of working with Mono 2.x.

Have we to compile it from code or has someone provided a link to download a working and precompiled version of MonoDev that works in Win 2000 and higher?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need MonoDevelop to build applications that run on Mono. The main feature of Mono is that it runs .NET assemblies without need for re-compilation. You can build in Visual Studio (including any of the free versions of Visual Studio Express) and run your applications under Mono without change, providing Mono supports the API's you're using.

You can use the Mono Migration Analyzer (MOMA) to test your assemblies to see if Mono will support them. It inspects the MSIL code directly, so it's very quick to test them.

I believe it is possible to run MonoDevelop on Win32: http://www.monodevelop.com/MonoDevelopWin32

You can run MonoDevelop on Windows using [AndLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/).

Comment: You mean to say that code compiled in .NET framework 1.1 or 2.0 will run directly on Mono 2.x?

If your answer is yes then that mean I will not have to install DotNET's framework on my PC?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Mono will run .NET EXE's without recompiling and without requiring .NET be installed. Additionally, Mono has a static linker which will allow you to build EXE's that will run on computers which don't have either Mono or .NET installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

Download one of the completely free Visual Studio Express versions: http://www.microsoft.com/express/product/default.aspx

Use SharpDevelop. There is no need to 'support' Mono, just develop like you normally would, and then copy your binaries over and Mono will run them.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, the point of Mono is to work the same as MS's .NET. You can develop in VS, then run it on Mono. That being said, if you really want to run MonoDevelop on Windows, don't let anyone tell you it can't be done. If you're curious about it, with a little bit of Cygwin hackery, I've been able to get MonoDevelop to compile cleanly on Windows, and run in an acceptable way. http://monodevelop.com/MonoDevelopWin32 has some instructions on how to get it working, but they are out of date. The current SVN trunk for MonoDevelop has better support for Windows, so try compiling with Cygwin if you're feeling daring.

Comment: I am a bit intimidated with all those command lines. Can you pass me the compiled EXE for MonoDev for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop does not currently run on Windows.  It currently runs on Linux and OSX.

On Windows, you can use Visual Studio or SharpDevelop and copy your binaries over to Linux or OSX to run them.

Comment: Actually, its now easier than that.  In the past few weeks we've moved MD over to MSBuild, so you can build and run it from VS.  So it "runs" on Windows.  What you will find is that it is too unstable to be usable.  It's easier to tell people it doesn't run on Windows, yet.  ;)

Comment: Where can I download MonoDevelop precompiled for Mac?